# High/low game in Pycharm

Tags: python

```
import random

name = input("Enter your name:") 
print("Hello and welcome to the game", name + "!")

lower_num = int(input("Enter the Lower bound:")) 
print()

higher_num = int(input("Enter the Higher bound:")) 
print()

user_num = random.randint(0, 10)
guess_num = int(input())

while True: 
    if user_num == guess_num: 
        print('\n"You guessed correctly!"\n') 
        break
    elif user_num > guess_num: 
        print('\n"Wrong, is too low."\n') 
    elif user_num < guess_num: 
        print('\n"Number is too high."\n')
```

This is what I have so far but is not working for me in Python.

Comment: What are the outputs that you are getting? Also higher num and lower num aren’t used

Comment: the person needs to guess a num and  the program says "Too, high or Too low" for the guessed num. If the person guesses the right num then the program says "you guessed correctly". But I'm getting an infinite loop.

Comment: and instead of lower num what should i used then?

Comment: You’ve declared and taken inputs for lower and higher num, but they aren’t needed in the program (you don’t use them)

Comment: Also, you have an infinite loop because you’ve declared guess_num outside of the loop and not presented the chance to change it within the loop (meaning if it’s not right the first time, you’ll never escape the loop)

Comment: Thank you i fixed it and it works. Doesn't gives me any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write the input inside the loop. If the person don't guess right num then the loop continue. For this, you need to write 'continue' under the elif. Then he can guess again.

```
while True:
    guess_num = int(input("Guess a number now:"))
    if user_num == guess_num:
        print('\n"You guessed correctly!"\n')
        break
    elif user_num > guess_num:
        print('\n"Wrong, is too low."\n')
        continue
    elif user_num < guess_num:
        print('\n"Number is too high."\n')
        continue
```

And what is the lower bound and higher bound for?